# Traverse PreOrder in BinarySearchTree (Java)

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

i need some help. I already runned my full code via JUnit but I still get errors. I think its because of my traverse code.

The purpose of the traverse code is to create a LinkedList in a in PreOrder.

for example: JUnit always says that something like that is wrong

```
assertArrayEquals( new Integer[]{2, 14, 26, 86, 122, 134, 182},
    Arrays.copyOf(tree.traversePreOrder(), tree.getSize(), Integer[].class));
```

---

```
@Override
public Object[] traversePreOrder() {
    BinaryTreeNode<T> x = root;
    LinkedList<Object> y = new LinkedList<Object>();

    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        y.add(x.value);
        y.add(travPreOrd(x.getLeft()));
        y.add(travPreOrd(x.getRight()));
    }
    return y.toArray();
}

public LinkedList<Object> travPreOrd(BinaryTreeNode<T> x) {
    BinaryTreeNode<T> tmp = x;
    LinkedList<Object> space = new LinkedList<Object>();

    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        space.add(tmp.getValue());
        space.add(travPreOrd(x.getLeft()));
        space.add(travPreOrd(x.getRight()));
    }
    return space;
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the results. it might be because you are adding `null` elements to the List

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza isnt that how LinkedList works? for example :   LinkedList<Object> is for example [null]. i add another object. -->  [Object1, null]. i add another object -->   [Object1, Object2, null]

Comment: @vandale how can i avoid adding nulls to my list?

Comment: check to see it the value is null before adding to the list: `LinkedList<Object> temp = travPreOrd(x.getLeft()); if(temp !=null) y.addAll(temp);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a big problem since you always add the results of `travPreOrd`, which is another `List<Object>` or `null` if the node doesn't exist.

The best solution for these cases is to maintain the overridden method as non-recursive and overload this method that uses recursion and has an argument where receives the container where it has to add the data:

```
public List<Object> travPreOrd(BinaryTreeNode<T> x) {
    BinaryTreeNode<T> tmp = x;
    List<T> space = new LinkedList<T>();
    travPreOrd(x, space);
    return space;
}

private void travPreOrd(BinaryTreeNode<T> x, List<T> space) {
    if (x == null) {
        return;
    }
    space.add(tmp.getValue());
    travPreOrd(x.getLeft(), space);
    travPreOrd(x.getRight(), space);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the contents of one list to another you use `addAll`.

So instead of:

```
    y.add(x.value);
    y.add(travPreOrd(x.getLeft()));
    y.add(travPreOrd(x.getRight()));
```

you want

```
    y.add(x.value);
    y.addAll(travPreOrd(x.getLeft()));
    y.addAll(travPreOrd(x.getRight()));
```

And then you're returning null from `travPreOrd`, which just makes your life harder - you then have to check for it and deal with it specially. Instead you can just return an empty list.

So instead of

```
if (x == null) {
    return null;
}
```

you could do

```
if (x == null) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

EDIT: Part of your problem is that you are using a `List<Object>` - which allows you to add anything to it, including other lists. If you instead used `List<Integer>`, or you used generics and had a `List<T>`, then the compiler would be able to tell you when you were doing the wrong thing.